# Websockets in WCF C# application to ORACLE database

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf, triggers, websocket

Is it possible to connect an ORACLE database from c# application like WCF using websockets? And how to send unsolicitated data from Oracle to c# application?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webSockets is what it says, communication between a web browser and server application. It has nothing to do to communicate to Oracle. To connect to Oracle from C# you can use ODP.Net library (also available from NuGet) which you can download from Oracle: [Oracle Data Provider for .Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

unsolicitated data? do not understand what your requirement is...

Comment: I dont know much about websockets.. I thought communication between C# application like WCF and any database (ORACLE in my case) is via http over TCP protocol. If so, we can upgrade http to websockets.  Am i wrong in my assumption?

Comment: Yes your assumption is wrong. You need to use a data adapter like ODP .Net or Oracle OleDb driver etc to communicate with Oracle. Websockets and Http are not in the equation.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Can I have 2 wcf applications talking over websockets? WCF and web applications combination?

Comment: Websockets are used to communicate between a web browser and web appplication. To communicate between 2 WCF applications you do not use WebSoockets. WCF supports different bindings using for different comm protocols. Please see this link for explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms731092.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response..appreciate it.. dont have enough reputation to vote up :)